# Toggle Editor not working after upgrade to EE 2.9.2

Tags: templates, ee2-upgrades, editor, template-manager

I just updated a site to EE 2.9.2 and the Template Editor is exhibiting funny behavior. If I click Toggle Editor, the row numbers truncate and the template text disappears. If I click it again, the template text is there but without the color coded text. See attachment. Has anyone else experienced this and is there a solution?

[image]

Comment: Which browser? Have you tried any other browsers, and cleared cache from your current?

Comment: It happens regardless of browser. Safari, Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue. I copied a new version of the "themes" folder from a fresh 2.9.2 install into my webroot. Then I put my third-party themes back in and all works great now. I think it's a set of styles or JS in the themes folder that you're missing.

Good luck!

Greg